# Can I know if my window handle is requested by another process?

Tags: windows, winapi, hwnd

There are notifications for this kind of events?
Or even for any function using my handle.

Comment: Handle, sorry. I got confused.

Comment: What do you mean "requested"?

Comment: When is returned by functions like EnumWindows or FindWindow.

Comment: Sounds incredibly unlikely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no mechanism for you to be notified that another application has been handed a window handle that belongs to you.